# Bought OBDII tool - System too rich

Tags: maintenance, gm

My 04 Isuzu Rodeo has had a too rich code for some time now. I definitely smell the fuel out of the exhaust. In the last 6 months I have had the following done to try to fix this issue:
New spark plugs, both cats replaced, new o2 sensors, new fuel filter, MAF and sensor replaced.

I'm still still having this issue. I bought a OBDII bluetooth tool and just purchased the Torque pro amp. I want to check coolant temps to see if its possibly the CTS. Can someone give me some pointers on what to look for on this app to pinpoint my issue? I'm new to the torque app and OBDII readers for that matter. Maybe I bought a faulty o2 sensor, I doubt it but I'm hoping the OBDII reader and torque pro can help me finally fix this issue. Any help is appreciated

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You say MAF and sensor replaced, which sensor?

Comment: In the Torque app select realtime information, then settings, then add display (whichever kind you want), then select which sensor to add.  Coolant temperature should be very close to both intake and ambient temperature when the vehicle has sat overnight with the key on and engine off.  After running the engine for a while, the temp should reach around 180 - 215 degrees (f)

Comment: Possible wiring issue?

Comment: My bet is the CTS is way out of range or dead.

Comment: @SergV - The MAF (Mass Air Flow) *is a sensor*. There's not two of them (well, not on your vehicle). Was it just the MAF, or did you replace some other sensor?

Comment: Oh yea. So I replaced the throttle body and maf sensor.  Sorry for the confusion....can I post screen shots of torque on here? I got some info for you guys

Comment: I have all the screen shots on the thread on the isuzu forum here:                                            http://www.planetisuzoo.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=130922

Comment: I can't add photos on comments. This sucks. Someone please help

Comment: Which engine do you have?

Comment: Ben, 3.2L engine